# Razor page: load data into a table -> slow rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We created a "log analyser" app to render multiple string entries into a webpage.
It's a dotnet6 app, using Razor pages.
It is a very minimastic UI, loading all data into a table, very similar to the MS tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio
The cs code first LoadLogs from the context. This part is well optimized with only inMemory DB and take only few ms, even for 50k entries.
However, the rendering on the table (maybe caused by the foreach in the cshtml page) takes ages, i.e. over 30sec for 50k entries.
See code below.

```
    [BindProperty]
    public IEnumerable<Models.Log> Logs { set; get; }
    public void OnPostLoad()
    {
         Logs = _contextHandler.LoadLogs();
    }

<tbody>
    @if (Model.Logs != null)
    {
        @foreach (var item in Model.Logs)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Time)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Level)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Service)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

Any idea about the real bottleneck? Look like the @Html.DisplayFor ?
The basic HTML Table might not optimal here.
Back in the days of Winforms for full desktop app, I was using Datagrid for such stuff.
What is the appropriate component in Asp.NET Core 6 and the minimalistic use of it, without 3rd party packages? Looking for "gridview" online, I only see examples with HTML Table.

Comment: You can refer to the reply to this post, which may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56994554/razor-table-loading-extremely-slow